# Does check for interface implementation inside an abstract class is an anti-pattern?

Tags: php, oop

Does the following code violate some OOP principle/pattern?

In particular I'm interested in the **instanceof** check inside the *Vehicle::whatCanDo()* method, that check if a subclass implents a specific interface.

At first sight it seems to violate the Liskov principle, but in fact it does not, because Airplane and Car classes are still interchangeable.

```php
abstract class Vehicle {

  public function whatCanDo() {   
    if ($this instanceof CanFly) {
      echo "can fly";
    }
  }

}

interface CanFly {
}

class Airplane extends Vehicle implements CanFly {
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are referring to SOLID, then it violates open/closed principle. If you need to add a new subclass, you will have to alter the superclass and actually indirectly cause all other subclasses to changes.

It also seems strange that an instance is testing what type it is. That crosses in the same minefield as "factory methods" and could be argued to constitute a single responsibility principle violation.

And it just a bad code in general, since you have a superclass, that writes to output buffer (uses `echo`).

Comment: We could presume that the echo is just for example, I suppose

Comment: @RobbieAverill hard to tell. I have seen way too many people having echos in their `class`  code. Basically every third PDO wrapper (this would actually need a separate rant) on StackOverflow does it.

Comment: @tereško the echo it's just for example, also class names are samples, my real code is different.

Comment: I don't understand why it violates open/closed principle. If I add a new subclass it can implement CanFly or not, but nor Vehicle nor Airplane classes should change.

For example I can implement a new class, say Ship, that implements a new interface, CanSwim. The only thing I have to alter is Vehicle::whatCanDo() in order to check if the current Vehicle can swim, and print "can swim".

Airplane and Car are so "open for extension, but closed for modification". Without modifying their code I'm able to add new Classes that both inherit from the same superclass, but acts slightly different.

Comment: @g4b0 then you need to read more about what *Open/Close Principle* actually means, because your "Only thing I have to alter ... is another class", is a textbook example of violation.

Comment: I'm happy to learn new things, do you have a good link where to examine in depth that topic, maybe with samples that matches my test case? Or better: can you share a sample of how do you should refactor my code?